# Db2 Warehouse (on Cloud): How to create external table?

Tags: amazon-s3, db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb, ibm-cloud-storage

Per the "[What's new in Db2 Warehouse on Cloud, ...](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21961758)" it is possible to create external tables. I looked at the linked documentation at the syntax on how to [create such an external table to link to my Amazon S3 and my IBM Bluemix / Softlayer Swift Cloud Object Storage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_create_ext_table.html). I have a Db2 Warehouse on Cloud with an "Entry Plan" and I don't see any restrictions mentioned.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE exttab1(a int,s varchar(50)) using
  (dataobject 'testdata.csv'
   swift('https://fra02.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/',
    'IBMOS12345:userid',
    '5---MyFullAPIKeyHere---b983',
    'henrik'
   )
  )
```

The above SQL statement gives me:

> SQL0104N: database/sql/driver: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664]
>   SQL0104N An unexpected token "EXTERNAL" was found following "CREATE".
>   Expected tokens may include: "". SQLSTATE=42601

What is the correct syntax? Are there restrictions I am not aware of?

Comment: No. It won't work. You are lucky that DB2 ignore your request. S3 can never be used as a data store, unless you intend to use it as read once in-memory data store. Otherwise, there is no way to "update" a S3 object. Even it allow you to do the rapid read and replace,  AWS is going to charge you $0.01  for every 10k READ/1k write + data transfer cost.

Comment: An external table is a simple method for data exchange between apps and to load smaller amounts of data. LOAD already has S3 and Swift support

Comment: perhaps, you should look at the code below swift, that mentioned S3,i.e. `S3 (endpoint, authKey1, authKey2, bucket)`.

Comment: I am using Cloud Object Storage with Swift API on the IBM Cloud. S3 is possible, not desired by me.

Comment: I will check the object storage access first.  
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/what-are-object-storage-authentication-endpoints-public-and-private-networks

Comment: I don't see anything that's wrong. How did you run the SQL statement? It didn't throw a syntax error when I just tried this in the Db2 WH SQL editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax and everything else was correct. I found out that my instance was not on the latest code level. The documentation was ahead of my cloud environment. I am now able to create the above external table and `SELECT` from it using SQL.